# Unable to check authorization and use session timeout in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get a simple MVC login project which will check whether correct user has logged in or not and then project navigation will be done keeping in check session timeout.

I've tried this
Here's [a link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095295/Check-Session-Timeout-by-Using-ActionFilters-in-MV)! 
Here's [a link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-login-application-using-Asp-Net-mvc/)!

HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult About(LoginUser model)
        {

            if (model.UserId == "")
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", "TestUserLoginID"); //hardcoding for current scenario

            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", model.UserId.ToString());  //hardcoding for current scenario
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Dataaaaa");
        }
```

DataaaaaController:
(here i want to use the timeout setting like if it is expired then just cancel all requests. kind of authentication)

```
[Timeout]

public class DataaaaaController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Timeout.cs:

```
public class Timeout: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static readonly HttpContext context;
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if (context.Session == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
                return;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

some changes in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
//some code
services.AddSession(s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
//some code
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
//some code
         app.UseSession();
//some code
}
```

I am expecting to set UserId with input data if it is valid(for now hardcoded). Once done then it will login to the application and user can do stuff or navigate. But when 30 sec of idle time is exhausted then it should not work and return to login page.

i guess i'm missing something, some code. 
also why is "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" used for ? 
one more doubt is if I want to save some logged in user data say id or name in session, then how can I access in JS or html file in the project further ?

Sorry for typing  error and new to MVC so half of the things are going above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following.. in your **Global.asax** add the following class

```
 public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

after that in every controller,for checking this session add the following

```
[SessionExpire] //this will check the session for every requests
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

If login is successful, insert the userid to session as

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"]="YOUR USER ID"
```

Comment: First there is no Global.asax page itself.
and HttpContext.Current throws an error. doesn't exists